# jQuery `this` works weird in user functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Please explain me, why does `this` behaves differently by self and with a function?

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.wtf = function () {
        // See in console
        // `this` returns what expected
        console.log(this);
        // `this.html()` returns only the first element's content
        console.log(this.html());
    }

    $('body').find(':header').wtf();
}(jQuery));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ta7Lmf7s/1/

Comment: What do you expect ?

Comment: That's what `html()` explicitly does, one of the first lines of the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/) clearly states that *" If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned"*

Comment: Why not tell us what you're trying to do here, and maybe you'll get an answer that solves the problem

Comment: Misunderstood the behavior and the response of jQuery: I thought that `$.fn` functions automatically iterates over each element passed to it, plus I missed the output, because I thought that `this` returns separate elements (because of the iteration), but it's an array. So the root of the question is my fault - sorry, I'm a JS/jQuery beginner, getting familiar with it about a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.html() returns the first matching element, so by using this.html() jQuery returns the first element it finds which in your case is the h1 top element.

More information on this can be found within the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Hope this helps answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and welcome to Stack Overflow!